How to modify XML node value depending on another node value using groovy script
<Products>
<Product>
  <PAYTERM_LABEL>Test 1</PAYTERM_LABEL>
  <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
  <DELETED_FLAG>X</DELETED_FLAG>
</Product>
<Product>
  <PAYTERM_LABEL>DO NOT USE</PAYTERM_LABEL>
  <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
  <DELETED_FLAG></DELETED_FLAG>
</Product>
</Products>

In above xml I would like to set value of <DELETED_FLAG> to “X” If <PAYTERM_LABEL> contains “DO NOT USE”
Thanks for any advice

Simple find/replace would do (modified your original XML for brevity):
import groovy.xml.*
  
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText '''
<Products>
<Product>
  <PAYTERM_LABEL>Test 1</PAYTERM_LABEL>
  <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
  <DELETED_FLAG>X</DELETED_FLAG>
</Product>
<Product>
  <PAYTERM_LABEL>Test 222</PAYTERM_LABEL>
  <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
  <DELETED_FLAG>X</DELETED_FLAG>
</Product>
<Product>
  <PAYTERM_LABEL>DO NOT USE</PAYTERM_LABEL>
  <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
  <DELETED_FLAG></DELETED_FLAG>
</Product>
</Products>
'''

xml.grep{ 'DO NOT USE' == it.PAYTERM_LABEL.text() }*.DELETED_FLAG*.replaceNode{ DELETED_FLAG 'X' }

XmlUtil.serialize xml

returns
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Products>
    
  <Product>
        
    <PAYTERM_LABEL>Test 1</PAYTERM_LABEL>
        
    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
        
    <DELETED_FLAG>X</DELETED_FLAG>
      
  </Product>
    
  <Product>
        
    <PAYTERM_LABEL>Test 222</PAYTERM_LABEL>
        
    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
        
    <DELETED_FLAG>NO</DELETED_FLAG>
      
  </Product>
    
  <Product>
        
    <PAYTERM_LABEL>DO NOT USE</PAYTERM_LABEL>
        
    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
        
    <DELETED_FLAG>X</DELETED_FLAG>
      
  </Product>
  
</Products>


import groovy.xml.*

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText '''
<Products>
<Product>
  <PAYTERM_LABEL>Test 1</PAYTERM_LABEL>
  <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
  <DELETED_FLAG>X</DELETED_FLAG>
</Product>
<Product>
  <PAYTERM_LABEL>DO NOT USE</PAYTERM_LABEL>
  <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
  <DELETED_FLAG></DELETED_FLAG>
</Product>
</Products>
'''

xml.'*'.findAll{ 'DO NOT USE' == it.PAYTERM_LABEL.text() }*.DELETED_FLAG*.replaceNode{ DELETED_FLAG ('X') }

println  groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)

I have achieved the same using XmlSlurper
